# Overview of hidden SharePoint links

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, hidden

Has someone a good tip for me for an overview of the hidden SharePoint links, such as `/_layout/15/News.aspx` or `/_layout/15/workbench.aspx`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below references for useful links to important pages in SharePoint:

1. [SharePoint URL Quick List](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sagarp/sharepoint-url-quick-list/)
2. [Useful Links For SharePoint Online Sites - Part One](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/useful-links-for-sharepoint-online-sites-part01)
3. [Useful Famous SharePoint URLs & Locations (increase your productivity in SharePoint On-Premise and O365)](https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-online/sharepoint-quick-reference-url/)
4. [SharePoint Layouts path URLs: Quick References](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53519.sharepoint-layouts-path-urls-quick-references.aspx)

There is no single where you can find all the links and their explanation. I hope you will find these references useful.

Comment: Thank you very much for the very helpful references!

Comment: Glad it helped you. Please [upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you and it will help others with same question in future to find the correct answer easily.